# How do I switch between two different View Controllers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to replicate the switching feature Instagram's app's video/photo upload section - [Video/Upload Section of Instagram app](http://g.recordit.co/mFILurEYKZ.gif).
 the switching between two view controllers has a swipe effect. If I'm to use tab bar controller, how do i customize the tab bar items to have text only that is bold enough.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Have you looked into `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController:animated:` or `popViewControllerAnimated:` methods?

Comment: Your video shows a tabbed interface, not a navigation between scenes.

Comment: Please google before you ask a question. There are a lot of links that provide solution to your problem on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push and pop the view controllers from the navigation stack.

When you PUSH a view controller you add it to the top of the stack.

When you POP a view controller you remove it from the top of the stack.

Here is an example of how to PUSH in Swift:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! MyViewController
self.navigationController.pushViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and to PUSH in Objective-C:

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

Comment: How do I make the bottom switching buttons?

Comment: add a UITabBarController and there is a delegate method called `didSelectViewController` for detecting which button was clicked.... or you can make your own custom view with buttons in it and add IBAction's to your buttons for switching views

Comment: If it's a UITabBarController how do I make the tabbar items text only (without icons) and bold enough text. if custom view with UIbuttons how do I make them stay the same (similar to UITabBar) between each view controller

Comment: if a UITabBarController you can set a custom view for the buttons without the default icons... if a custom view with UIButtons then you can use auto layout to make them look similar to a UITabBarController and just copy/paste that view into each of your view controllers